# Cron Job doesn't work when sending data to zabbix

Tags: bash, cron, zabbix

i'm following this guide https://github.com/omni-lchen/zabbix-cloudwatch/tree/master/cron.d
 i'm logged as centos user, even tried replacing root with centos but the same

manually all works fine-data sent to zabbix

```
 /opt/zabbix/cloudwatch/zabbix-cloudwatch/cron.d/cron.Lambda.sh "lambdaAmiCleanup" "aws_north_virginia" "localhost" "default" "us-east-1"
{'host': 'aws_north_virginia', 'value': 1.0, 'key': u'Lambda.Invocations.Sum["default","us-east-1","lambdaAmiCleanup"]', 'clock': 1533286680}
{'host': 'aws_north_virginia', 'value': 0.0, 'key': u'Lambda.Errors.Sum["default","us-east-1","lambdaAmiCleanup"]', 'clock': 1533286680}
{'host': 'aws_north_virginia', 'value': 334.57, 'key': u'Lambda.Duration.Average["default","us-east-1","lambdaAmiCleanup"]', 'clock': 1533286680}
{'host': 'aws_north_virginia', 'value': 0.0, 'key': u'Lambda.Throttles.Sum["default","us-east-1","lambdaAmiCleanup"]', 'clock': 1533286680}
```

but when scheduling cron job data are no sent (crontab -e), i tried capturing output to txt file, file is created but it's empty

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/zabbix/cloudwatch/zabbix-cloudwatch/cron.d

*/1 * * * * root /opt/zabbix/cloudwatch/zabbix-cloudwatch/cron.d/cron.Lambda.sh "lambda-cllean-unknown-instances" "aws_north_virginia" "localhost" "default" "us-east-1" >/tmp/2.txt
```

file is not even created if specified in crontab file

Comment: This is likely because some environment variable or permissions (you haven't mentioned as which user crontab is installed and as which user you manually tested). Add `stderr` redirection (` 2>&1` at the end of that line), it might give you more info.

Comment: added 2>&1 but same output: running manually as centos user, set centos instead of root, but the same

Answer (score 0):

started to work in following way (removed root):

```
crontab -e
/opt/zabbix/cloudwatch/zabbix-cloudwatch/cron.d/cron.Lambda.sh "lambdaAmiCleanup" "aws_north_virginia" "localhost" "default" "us-east-1"
```

Thanks @Richlv for hint